# dsp2 and sp3 hybrid orbital shapes in coordination chemistry

Tags: coordination-compounds, hybridization

Why is $\mathrm{dsp}^2$ square planar but $\mathrm{sp}^3$ tetrahedral in shape? I am unable to find a reason anywhere. I know how to figure which hybridisation a compound is, but not *why*.

Comment: How do you think you find the hybridisation of a molecule?

Comment: @bon I find the number of electrons, then check if the ligand is strong field or weak field. If it is strong I pair the electrons. The left over orbitals are used by the ligand, so they all get hybridised.

Comment: ‘Stop using hybridisation to explain complexes’ is the answer to your question.

Comment: Square planar usually happens if there is a reason to keep two electrons (sometimes even one) in a $\mathrm{d_{z^2}}$ orbital for stabilisation reasons.